# Convert ASCII string to integer string

Tags: c#, .net

I can read a string of bytes via UDP but cannot convert them to a string of integers.

```
try {

       IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

      // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.

       Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
       string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

        // Uses the IPEndPoint object to determine which host responded
       Console.WriteLine("Received: \n\n " +
                                          returnData.ToString());
       Console.WriteLine("\nSource:\n\n " +
                                         "IP: " + RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() +
                                         "\n Port: " +
                                         RemoteIpEndPoint.Port.ToString());

        //split string by delimiter
        string[] arrString = returnData.Split(new char[] { ',' });

        int[] data = new int[arrString.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrString.Length; i++)
        {

          data[i] = int.Parse(arrString[i]);


         }


         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500000000);
         // udpClient.Close();


          }  
       catch (Exception e ) {
                  Console.WriteLine("\nError: \n");
                  Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500000000);
        };
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting? And is the string you receive actually a comma-separated list of single digits?

Comment: What's the problem?  Is it slow?  Try a smaller Sleep().

Comment: The byte array looks like the following: ??, ??, ??, ??

Comment: Other guys had answered the question, just consider using`Console.ReadKey()` instead of `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500000000)` for pausing application.

Answer (score 1):

[**How to: Convert a byte Array to an int (C# Programming Guide)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx)

```
byte[] bytes = { 0, 0, 0, 25 };

// If the system architecture is little-endian (that is, little end first),
// reverse the byte array.
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(bytes);

int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", i);
// Output: int: 25
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IPAddress` class has some helper methods to convert bytes back and forth between network and host order, namely: [HostToNetworkOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/653kcke1.aspx) and [NetworkToHostOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1886wea.aspx)